# How to use just one column when multiple columns are returned from subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery

Say I have a subquery like

```
select deptNo, count(*) 
from employee group by deptNo
```

and I want use just count(*) in my main query, how can I do that?

eg: Queries like `count(*) in (select deptNo, count(*) from employee group by deptNo)`;
Or what is the alternative to do it??

Comment: Just select `count(*)` in subquery

Comment: Just remove the `deptNo` column. Besides: `count(*) IN (...)` looks very strange. Are you sure you don't want a having clause?

Comment: you simply can't do that with an IN clause. If that what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't remove deptNo as I'm grouping by that attribute and this was just an example. Actually I want the average of all the count(*)'s  obtained in the subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select avg(cnt) 
from (
    select deptNo, count(*) as cnt
    from employee group by deptNo) src
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.count1  from 
(select deptNo,count(*) as count1 from employee group by deptNo) as t
```

Try to have an alias name for the count in the inner query.I assume you need only the column count1 here.(I have named the column as count1)